Reductio ad Absurdum
See below is a quote from the book "An Introduction to Logic an its Philosophy (Peter K. Schotch 2006)" that I I don't understand.
Bold text in parenthesis is a comment I added to make the text clear.I added the bold and Italic characters are added and the text between parenthesis.

This particular derivation (reductio ab absurdum) is nearly always the cause of tears, or at least of bad language when it is first assigned to beginning students. There isn’t any doubt that it is difficult, although more or less blindly following rules of thumb can carry one nearly all the way through to the end. It may be that this is a difficult (early) exercise, not only because we must resort to reductio immediately, even before we can try some other way, but also that we must use one reductio subderivation inside the scope of another. If we think about it for a bit, it will be hard not to see this as a kind of watershed for the Classical approach to logic. Perhaps nowhere else in the very beginnings of logic, do we sail quite so close to the wind or travel quite so far away from our immediate intuitions. If, for instance, we think that reductio reasoning is only allowable when the assumption may be seen to contribute to the production of a contradiction, then nesting of [¬E] subderivations one inside another will not be legitimate in most cases. If the exterior subderivation really does lead to a contradiction, then that contradiction must be there before we start the interior subderivation.
In other words, if we were to try to fix the classical negation rules (Negation Introduction and Negation Elimination) by placing a condition on its application to only consistent (without the assumption which is being reduced) sets of formulas (as Γ) —perhaps along the lines of:
Γ⊬ ⊥ & Γ , A ⊢ ⊥ ⇒   Γ ⊢ ~A
we can never perform a reductio within the scope of another. It would follow from this that any derivation which required the use of a reductio subderivation inside the scope of another could be done in the new system. It is beyond the scope of this book to answer the question of whether there are any such derivations in CSL (Consequence Sentential Logic) and exactly which logic would result from the restriction on the classical negation rules.

I understand that there is a problem of circularity. I will try to illustrate it with an example from the book. To prove that ~(A V ~A) is not derivable, we begin a Subderivation with as assumption 'A', by Disjuntion Introduction we infere 'A V ~A', contradicting the assumption of the first derivation (the Premise), and discharge that first subderivation. We try a second subderivation assuming ~A, and again by Disjunction Introduction we infere ~A V A, contradicting definitely the Premise. But since the Premise is still a contradiction, we cannot use an Ab Absurdum inference.
First I'm not sure that is the point.
Secondly the work is made assuming that the Premise is not a Falsum and so the system is consistent.
Stay the problem on the core of deduction?
It's obvious that the inference rule is built as the material condional and the MC A ⊃ B itself is a True Function of A ∧ ~B, ~(A ∧ ~B).
From a semantic point of view,  ⊃ would be significant only when the antecedent and the consequent are both True. Therefore, the conjunction ∧ is closer to a meaning connection link between its conjuncts than the Material Implication is for antecedent and consequent.
In other words with ⊃ the Truth is the negation of falsify and with ∧ it's Truth is the negation of Truth. We bind ourselves to a rule that excludes the middle. We must choose to identify it with one of the extremes. It is not enough to say that middle is excluded.
However it seems from the connectors ∧ and ⊃ that the choice between Truth and Falsity doesn't follow the same rule for each of them.
Maybe this is what the author is asking about, but I'm not sure.
I searched in textbooks but wasn't able to find a development of the issue.
I apologize to educated logicians if I am stating the obvious.

I thought Kant had a list of antinomies he wasn't comfortable with. I feel there's a metalogical element to the reductio ad absurdum, obstructing full katalepsy of the idea.

Short answer.
The issue Schotch is discussing is not one of circularity. He is pointing out that using the rule of reductio ad absurdam in an unrestricted way leads directly to the principle of explosion, i.e. the rule that from a contradiction anything follows. As he says, many beginning students find this surprising and unintuitive, but it is a feature of classical logic. If we try to avoid explosion by building in restrictions on the rules of inference of classical logic, we get a mess because the rules will work in some contexts and not in others.
Longer version.
The classical rule for negation introduction can be written in sequent form as follows:
   Γ, A ⊢ ⊥ 
   ---------    ¬I
    Γ ⊢ ¬A

(I've converted the ==> in your quoted text into an inference line, because I have an aversion to double arrows.)
The idea behind this rule is simple enough. If from A we can derive a contradiction then A is false, so we can introduce ¬A. The Γ here is doing the job of saying that this works within any context such as a theory or a set of premises.
But this rule does not require that A is needed for the derivation of ⊥. This is what the quoted text is referring to when it speaks of an assumption contributing to the production of a contradiction. If Γ itself is inconsistent, then Γ, A ⊢ ⊥ holds, and hence so must Γ ⊢ ¬A, whatever A is. If we try to work around this by adding a restriction Γ ⊬ ⊥ (which requires Γ to be consistent) then we can no longer use the negation introduction rule in any context without establishing whether Γ is consistent. This is undesirable in a proof system: we want our rules to work everywhere.
In classical logic we choose to accept explosion. It may seem unintuitive, but once you understand why it is a feature, it is not so strange. Peter Geach attempted to set out an alternative account of entailment that avoids explosion while retaining classical logic, but it was criticised by Dale and others and for my part I don't believe it works. The other way to avoid explosion is to depart from the classical approach to logic and use a paraconsistent logic.

Peter Geach, Entailment, Logic Matters, Blackwell, (1972), pp. 175-186.
Peter Geach, Entailment Again, Logic Matters, Blackwell, (1972), pp. 186-188.
Peter Geach, On Entailment, Analysis, 1975, Vol. 35, No. 6, pp. 186-187.
A. J. Dale, Geach on Entailment, Philosophical Review, Vol. 82, No. 2 (1973), pp. 215-219.
A. J. Dale, Geachian Entailment, Philosophical Review, Vol. 87, No. 3 (1978), pp. 423-426.


It's an excellent and pedagogical answer. It seemed to me that he criticized the ad Absurdum reason in a second order subderivation (a sub-subderivation. I found 2 pages in the introduction to Formal Logic of Peter Smith. I need to think again where in the middle of the reasoning you're already not sure from of the consistency of the system and the Red AA become questionable.

I read interesting insides in Peter Smith Introduction to Formal Logic §6.5, §17.1, §20.9 , his book is much better than the book of Schotch.

Well-explained! Kudos! Introductory logic books, don't really explain the ins and outs of the reductio. Wikipedia had a strong article on it.

@Bumble I reread several times the stuff in the book. There's something in my question I think is not addressed in your answer. For instance, we have the main derivation, represented by the first column from the left, and nested subderivations expanding toward the right side. Assume that the first subderivation already holds a contradiction when it's discharged. And the next subderivation leads to a contradiction. At first glance, this last contradiction would not lead to negate the assumption of the last subderivation because it's already in the scope of an inconsistent set of premises.
